# How to clear browser cache from webobjects application?

Tags: ios, caching, webobjects

In log out action, we are terminating the session by using terminate() method of session. But after log-out, if we click on back button of the browser, i can able to see the content of last page, but i am unable to do any action(This is fine). If we clear the browser cache after log-out, there is no problem. So we found, it is because of browser cache.

So please let us know how to clear the browser cache from webobjects application programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it may retain cached information when you close out the UIWebView. I've tried removing a UIWebView from my UIViewController, releasing it, then creating a new one. The new one remembered exactly where I was at when I went back to an address without having to reload everything (it remembered my previous UIWebView was logged in).

So a couple of suggestions:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
```

This would remove a cached response for a specific request. There is also a call that will remove all cached responses for all requests ran on the UIWebView:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

After that, you can try deleting any associated cookies with the UIWebView:

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {

        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Deepak